# What is the role of struct 'PGPROC' in PostgreSQL?

Tags: c, postgresql, struct

When I read PostgreSQL codes, I found a struct named 'PGPROC': I don't quite understand the function of it.  That is, why does PostgreSQL use this 'PGPROC' and which role does role it in PG.

```
struct PGPROC                                                                                                         
{
    /* proc->links MUST BE FIRST IN STRUCT (see ProcSleep,ProcWakeup,etc) */
    SHM_QUEUE   links;          /* list link if process is in a list */

    PGSemaphoreData sem;        /* ONE semaphore to sleep on */
    int         waitStatus;     /* STATUS_WAITING, STATUS_OK or STATUS_ERROR */

    LocalTransactionId lxid;    /* local id of top-level transaction currently
                                 * being executed by this proc, if running;
                                 * else InvalidLocalTransactionId */

    TransactionId xid;          /* id of top-level transaction currently being
                                 * executed by this proc, if running and XID
                                 * is assigned; else InvalidTransactionId */

    TransactionId xmin;         /* minimal running XID as it was when we were
                                 * starting our xact, excluding LAZY VACUUM:
                                 * vacuum must not remove tuples deleted by
                                 * xid >= xmin ! */

    int         pid;            /* This backend's process id, or 0 */
    BackendId   backendId;      /* This backend's backend ID (if assigned) */
    Oid         databaseId;     /* OID of database this backend is using */
    Oid         roleId;         /* OID of role using this backend */

    bool        inCommit;       /* true if within commit critical section */

    uint8       vacuumFlags;    /* vacuum-related flags, see above */

    /* Info about LWLock the process is currently waiting for, if any. */
    bool        lwWaiting;      /* true if waiting for an LW lock */
    bool        lwExclusive;    /* true if waiting for exclusive access */
    struct PGPROC *lwWaitLink;  /* next waiter for same LW lock */

    /* Info about lock the process is currently waiting for, if any. */
    /* waitLock and waitProcLock are NULL if not currently waiting. */
    LOCK       *waitLock;       /* Lock object we're sleeping on ... */
    PROCLOCK   *waitProcLock;   /* Per-holder info for awaited lock */
    LOCKMODE    waitLockMode;   /* type of lock we're waiting for */
    LOCKMASK    heldLocks;      /* bitmask for lock types already held on this
                                 * lock object by this backend */

    /*
     * All PROCLOCK objects for locks held or awaited by this backend are
     * linked into one of these lists, according to the partition number of
     * their lock.
     */
    SHM_QUEUE   myProcLocks[NUM_LOCK_PARTITIONS];

    struct XidCache subxids;    /* cache for subtransaction XIDs */

    /*
     * Identifies whether this process is one of the special CQ
     * processes. "0" indicates normal PG processes; CQ processes are
     * identified by one of the constants from cqcommon.h.
     */
    uint8 cqProcType;
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're talking about `struct PGPROC` in `src/include/storage/proc.h`.

There's a comment that explains what it's for, immediately above it.

```
/*
 * Each backend has a PGPROC struct in shared memory.  There is also a list of
 * currently-unused PGPROC structs that will be reallocated to new backends.
 *
 * ....
 */
struct PGPROC
{
    ....
```

but I admit it's perhaps a little terse for someone who's not used to Pg's architecture.

PostgreSQL backend processes can't see each other's memory directly, nor can the postmaster see into PostgreSQL backend process memory. Yet they need some way to communicate and co-ordinate, and the postmaster needs a way to keep track of them.

That's what `struct PGPROC` is for. It's allocated into an array inside `struct PROC_HDR` (see slightly later in the file), in the `PGPROC     *allProcs` member. It's a simple pointer not an explicit array because it's variable size and is allocated at runtime. Per the comment, each backend process has a `PGPROC` array entry.

`PGPROC` entries are used to handle wait/latch synchronization, transaction ID co-ordination, lock waits, the `pg_stat_activity` view, hot standby conflict signalling, and all sorts of other inter-process co-ordination activities. It's not the only channel - signals are also used, stats are reported via UDP to the stats collector, and there are various shared memory channels for other things - but it's a major one.

All backends can see `PGPROC` entries in `PROC_HDR`, so they can communicate with their peers. Without this, things like lock waits would be nearly impossible to implement.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Now I have known that PGPROC is used for communication through backend processes. And it will helps me a lot to understand codes.